# eslint plugin for react-dnd

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-dnd

I am building a solution with react-dnd and discovered I was missing dependencies to the hooks.

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const [, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    drop: () => {
      dispatch(drop({ itemId: props.id }))
    }
  }), [props.id]); // <-- I was missing this!
  ... 
}
```

For native react-hooks `useEffect`, etc.,  there are eslint plugins detecting this, but I received no warnings for this.

Do such rules exist for react-dnd